# Исключение из постоянного перенаправления *.domain -> files.domain в NGINX

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, администрирование, настройка

Есть постоянное перенаправление всех субдоменов на основной сайт. Необходимо исключить субдомен files из этого постоянного перенаправления.

Читал [статью на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037510/how-to-exclude-specific-subdomains-server-name-in-nginx-configuration), но ничего не понял.

В идеале должно получится так:

- https://domain.ru -> https://domain.ru
- https://*.domain.ru -> https://domain.ru
- https://files.domain.ru -> https://files.domain.ru

Файл основного домена с перенаправлением:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name domain.ru;
        root /var/www/sites/domain.ru/;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/domain.ru.key;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;


}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name *.domain.ru;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/domain.ru.key;

        return 301 https://domain$request_uri;
}
```

Файл с выделенным субдоменом:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name domain.ru;
        root /var/www/sites/__subdomain/domain.ru/;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/domain.ru/domain.ru.key;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name files.domain.ru;

        return 301 https://files.domain.ru$request_uri;
}
```

---

Изменил порядок подгрузки конфигов.

И поскольку редирект постоянный, а не временный, браузер это запомнит и еще нескоро забудет и будет редиректить до усрачки несмотря на обновившийся конфиг на вебсервере. Кэш чистить придется.

Comment: Просто определить серверный блок с таким именем слушающий 443 порт как и остальные блоки

Comment: @Alexey Ten, он уже определён в файле с выделенным субдоменом.

Comment: Виду Там только 80 порт

Comment: @AlexeyTen, наведите пример. Не понимаю о чём вы.

Comment: Хм, а вы понимаете как вообще работает http и что в частности в nginx означает директива listen?

Comment: добавить еще один блок `server { listen 443; server_name files.domain.ru; ... остальной конфиг для https://files.domain.ru }`